# How to apply only one axis Transform?

Tags: transforms, axis

I have a model which rotation is x-38. y-30. z-40. (for example)
How can i apply only "X" axis ? And keep other rotations the same.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You want to apply only $x$ rotation, so assuming your Euler order is XYZ (or assuming the axis you want to rotate by is the first non-zero rotation), all you have to do is to hover your mouse over that rotation, <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, $\color{green}{█}\color{#888}{0█}$ *click*, type zero <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>↩ Enter</kbd>, go to *Edit Mode* <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to rotate around local $x$ axis, <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste the copied rotation value.

However if the assumptions were incorrect, it's tricky to think on what exactly should "applying a single rotation axis" be; I imagine it should be making setting a single rotation to $0$, keeping all other properties unchanged, and keeping the appearance of the object unchanged. I think the best way to achieve that would be to press <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> and paste the below code into the console:

```py
coords=[C.object.matrix_world @ v.co for v in C.object.data.vertices];
C.object.rotation_euler.y = 0
mat = C.object.matrix_world.inverted()
for v, co in zip(C.object.data.vertices, coords):
    v.co = mat @ co
    
C.area.type = 'VIEW_3D'
```

Make sure to change the 2nd line if you want to apply a different axis than $y$.

Comment: @RobinBetts You're correct, I think at first I rotated in both object and edit mode, and then changed the technique to a little more efficient. Impressive you caught the error :)

Comment: Phew! I had to check ... UV'd you, and _then_ thought... hang on a minute! :)

Comment: If you wanna apply something other than `rotation_euler`, remember not just to replace the axis letter, but the word for the kind of movement as well, such as `location`.